# My Discord bot isn't responding to commands / Junior coder

Tags: discord, discord.py

here is my code, tried everything i could but still at a dead end. Would appreciate any help to this junior coder

happy to just keep typing until it let me post because it says my msg is mostly just code and it needs more details.

```
import requests
import io
import base64
from PIL import Image
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import Intents, File

intents = Intents.default()
Intents.message_content = True #v2
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)

@bot.command(name='generate')
async def generate(ctx, prompt: str):
    print(f"Received command to generate image with prompt: {prompt}")
    url = "http://127.0.0.1:7860"
    payload = {
        "prompt": prompt,
        "steps": 5
    }

    response = requests.post(url=f'{url}/sdapi/v1/txt2img', json=payload)
    r = response.json()

    for i in r['images']:
        image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(base64.b64decode(i.split(",", 1)[0])))

        png_payload = {
            "image": "data:image/png;base64," + i
        }
        response2 = requests.post(url=f'{url}/sdapi/v1/png-info', json=png_payload)

        image_path = 'output.png'
        image.save(image_path)
        print(f"Image saved as {image_path}")

        with open(image_path, 'rb') as img_file:
            await ctx.send(file=File(img_file, 'output.png'))

# Replace this with your actual bot token
bot_token = 'TOKEN'
bot.run(bot_token)

commands in discord channels aren't being recognized, made sure bot has admin permission and is showing in list of users in that particular channels
```

Answer (score 2):

Message content privileged intent is still missing. On line 8, you assigned `discord.Intents.default()` to a variable. However, on line 9, you are setting `message_content` of the *object* to `True`. Thus, the variable wasn't updated.

```
intents = Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True #  Note casing
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)
```

With `from discord import Intents`, `Intents` with an uppercase `I` is the object.

More about [discord.Intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Intents)